# Item statistic "CreatedBy" returning empty string

Tags: sitecore-api

I'm trying to get the creator of an item, but when I access the CreatedBy property, it returns an empty string. When I debugged I could see the all the other fields were populated, but not the CreatedBy:

[image]

```
var contextDatabase = Sitecore.Context.Database;
Item blogPost = contextDatabase.GetItem(data.ID);
var creator =  blogPost.Statistics.CreatedBy;
```

I really don't know why it shows as empty. Any idea why?

Edit: In the content tree, in the statistic field section, the CreatedBy is there:

[image]

Comment: can you try in this way: blogPost.Fields["__created by"].Value

Comment: @SitecoreClimber Yeah that worked, thanks. I still dont understand why the other way  doesnt work, that;s weird.

Comment: I am transforminng my comment in an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**"Statistics.CreatedBy"** property does not return standard values.

To fix this problem please use : **blogPost.Fields["__created by"].Value**

Statistics.Created use next code:

```
private string GetFieldValue(ID fieldId)
{
    Field field = this._item.Fields[fieldId];
    return field.GetValue(false, false) ?? string.Empty;
}
```

where field.GetValue has next parameters

```
public virtual string GetValue(bool allowStandardValue, bool allowDefaultValue)
```

Comment: Wut? :D  So if Creator happens to be the same account as the one who created the Standard Values item, this applies?

Comment: Oh I see, thanks really!. Do you know where can I get the API documentation. I've looked for it everywhere, with no luck at all.

Comment: Also, why is it there? the  "Statistics.CreatedBy" if it's not gonna be used?